# Unable to backup the database or apply migrations

Tags: database, mysql, updating

I'm running CraftCMS via 3 Docker containers in 1 Docker network:

- **Container 1** - MySQL
- **Container 2** - Nginx
- **Container 3** - PHP:7.4-fpm

When I run `php craft update craft` from **container 3** and choose to backup the db, I get this error:

```bash
Backup the database? (yes|no) [yes]:yes
Backing up the database ... error: The shell command "mysqldump --defaults-extra-file="/tmp/hvncbmcornry.cnf" --add-drop-table --comments --create-options --dump-date --no-autocommit --routines --default-character-set=utf8 --set-charset --triggers --no-tablespaces --single-transaction --no-data --result-file="/app/storage/backups/my-site--2021-05-26-052145--v3.6.15.sql" craftcms && mysqldump --defaults-extra-file="/tmp/hvncbmcornry.cnf" --add-drop-table --comments --create-options --dump-date --no-autocommit --routines --default-character-set=utf8 --set-charset --triggers --no-tablespaces --no-create-info --ignore-table=craftcms.assetindexdata --ignore-table=craftcms.assettransformindex --ignore-table=craftcms.sessions --ignore-table=craftcms.templatecaches --ignore-table=craftcms.templatecachequeries --ignore-table=craftcms.templatecacheelements --ignore-table=craftcms.cache --ignore-table=craftcms.templatecachecriteria craftcms >> "/app/storage/backups/my-site--2021-05-26-052145--v3.6.15.sql"" failed with exit code 127: sh: 1: mysqldump: not found
```

It looks like the `mysqldump` command doesn't exist in Container 3 as I don't get a result when running: `which mysqldump`. Running this *which* command from **container 1** does however return: `/usr/bin/mysqldump`. But in this container, I don't have access to my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to install mysq-client but got this error: `Package 'mysql-client' has no installation candidate` After installing `mariadb-client`, everything worked as expected!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your php-fpm container 3 needs to install the MySQL client tools in it, so that `mysqldump` is available in the container similar to https://github.com/craftcms/docker/blob/main/7.4/dev.Dockerfile#L18